# GoogleApiClient Status 12501 Error Login

Tags: android

I am getting a `severe error` on 20% of my user base logins.

The GoogleApiClient using `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` sometimes get status `12501` at my `release environment`.

I myself cannot reproduce. I noticed many people with the same doubt in StackOverflow and even followed their tips but I still can not solve the problem.

According to `Google documentation`, I am using requestIdToken associated to my oauth web api key. So apparently everything is ok. Anyone could help me? Any tips? Thanks for help.

```
private void configureGoogleSignIn() {
    try {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestId()
                .requestIdToken(getResources().getString(R.string.oauth_web_google_signin))
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                .build();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        WrapperLog.logError(GeneralLogin.class, e);
    }
}


@OnClick(R.id.sign_in_button)
public void onClickGoogleSignIn() {
    Log.i(TAG, "clicked to google sign in");
    try {
        showProgressLoading();
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        WrapperLog.logError(GeneralLogin.class, e);
        errorLogoutGoogle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
        return;
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

    // Inner User login methods

}
```

Comment: Please be aware of increasing chances to give you correct and precise answer – share you code, give steps to reproduce or/and test data will increase your chances to get an good answer soon

Comment: Thanks for tips @StepanNovikov .